# CustomValidator's ClientValidationFunction: is there a way to set trimmed value back to input?

Tags: webforms

Before validating I trim `arguments.Value`. If validation fails, I want to place trimmed value back to input. Changing `arguments.Value` does not have effect. `Sender` (the 1st argument in `ClientValidationFunction`) is a validation control message layout, not original input.

I see the only way: manual search input element by id, or name, or class, but it makes my  `ClientValidationFunction` be aware about certain input, and I have to set `ClientID` or unique class to my input.

Answer (score 0):

Validator object that is passed as `val` parameter of client validation function has `controltovalidate` field which holds unique ID of the server control (specified in `ControlToValidate` property of `CustomValidator`). So you can easily set value back to your control as following:

```
function trimAndSetBack(val, args) {
    // val.controltovalidate will always hold unique id 
    // of the server control so document.getElementById will work always
    ValidatorSetValue(val.controltovalidate, ValidatorTrim(eventArgs.Value));
}

function ValidatorSetValue(id, value) {
    var control;
    control = document.getElementById(id);

    if (typeof (control.value) == "string" && (control.type != "radio" || control.checked == true)) {
        control.value = value;
        return true;
    }

    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < control.childNodes.length; i++) {
        if (ValidatorSetValue(control.childNodes[i], value)) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

`ValidatorSetValue` is a bit modified version of standard `ValidatorGetValueRecursive` function. Recursion is needed if you dealing with user controls where input control is nested inside.